# How can I view a deleted question?

Tags: support, comments, specific-question, deleted-questions

One of the questions (Does plain C# follow MVC architecture?) I posted were deleted by the moderator before I noted down the comments (as some comments were very helpful).

Can someone/moderator please help me to undelete it for sometime, so I can view the information.

Comment: If you have the link of that question, You can ask someone with 10K+ rep user to read comments for you on chat.

Comment: That's great, but I am new here, so don't know anyone with 10K rep.. A copy paste of the comments would be more than enough. The link goes to the page which says *"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142939/does-plain-c-sharp-follow-mvc-architecture#comment21318525_15142939"*...

Comment: @hims056: The question title was enough; Google indexes SO really fast these days.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Makes sense. Didn't think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full copy of the comments on that [specific deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142939/does-plain-c-sharp-follow-mvc-architecture) (visible to 10K+ users):

> - What do you mean by "plain C# without .Net"? – mbeckish yesterday
> - C# without .NET? And how is C# is equal to MVC? MVC is a framework, C# is a language, and .NET is a platform. – bas yesterday
> - No. Plain c# is a language specification with no concept of
>     models views or controllers. – spender yesterday
> - This is less an apples-to-apples comparison and more of an apples-to-filet mignon comparison. – Brian yesterday
> - @mbeckish:
>     the language spec without the BCLs, presumably. – Michael Petrotta
>     yesterday
> - @mbeckish Please be kind, so if one learns C#, can he automatically get qualified to have learnt C#.Net as well? – aspiring yesterday
> - @MichaelPetrotta I think that's what I am after. – aspiring yesterday
> - MVC is a programming paradigm that basically says you
>     should separate logic from presentation. MVC can be applied to almost
>     any programming language but it's not an inherent part of it. C# is
>     just one of them and you can adhere to the MVC paradigm or you don't.
>     And .Net is the Framework that C# runs on. Think JavaVM and Java. –
>     Corak yesterday
> - @MichaelPetrotta - That would be my only guess, but I assume the OP meant something else, because the question doesn't seem to be about
>     the language spec. – mbeckish yesterday
> - @Brian I am unable to decode the English statement in terms of this question, can you provide a nooby proof explanation? :) –
>     aspiring yesterday
> - What?? C# is just a language. MVC is a software pattern or architecture – HighCore yesterday
> - @aspiring - You can start
>     here: stackoverflow.com/q/2724864/21727 . Google is also your friend. – mbeckish yesterday
> - @Corak thank you. So knowing C# language specifics doens't mean that one knows .Net. But C# can be learnt on .Net framework with .Net
>     specifications. Thus that means I can use MVC for C# as for Java as
>     well as when using C# for .Net framework. Thanks, that solves the
>     confusion.. – aspiring yesterday
> - For all intents and purposes: there is no C# without .Net. Think of it like this: You write software in C# this get's compiled to an
>     intermediate language (CLR) and .Net takes that and translates it to
>     the actual Processor... not very acurate, but maybe it helps. – Corak
>     yesterday
> - @Corak so does it mean, C# must be compiled on .Net framework? Can't we write C# codes without using .Net specifics/components? e.g.
>     VB and then VB.Net – aspiring yesterday
> - Like I said, think of ".Net" as "JavaVM" and "C#" as "Java". – Corak yesterday
> - @aspiring - If you are using Visual
>     Studio to create a C# app, then you are using the .NET framework's
>     class library and virtual machine. However, someone could always write
>     their own compiler to compile C# syntax into a standalone executable. – mbeckish yesterday

Comment: Thank you so very much! @Martijin :D Perhaps there could be a *feature* to ask moderators about deleted posts :D

Comment: @aspiring Your post was deleted by community votes, and not a moderator, FWIW.

Comment: @RaghavSood thanks for letting me know. Perhaps getting closed would be helpful and then allow the OP to delete it - to avoid cases like mine :)

Comment: @aspiring The OP is always allowed to delete it (though there are some restrictions if it has upvoted and accepted answers, I believe). Usually questions aren't delete after being closed, but they can be if 3 users with enough rep cast a delete vote